# Meta box plugin WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using Meta box plugin for WordPress and don't understand how to make fields output appears in pages. I want to use checkbox to add/remove div's class. For example this is code for my page template:

```
<?php
<div class="HOW TO APPEAR CLASS FROM META BOX CHECK BOX HERE??">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div> 
?>
```

and this is metabox array from metabox plugin:

```
array(
'name' => __( 'Checkbox', 'rwmb' ),
'id' => "{$prefix}checkbox",
'type' => 'checkbox',
// Value can be 0 or 1
'std' => 1,
),
```

How to add class in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$my_metabox = rwmb_meta('checkbox_meta_key'); //Replace checkbox_meta_key with the key you defined.
?>
<div class="<?php if($my_metabox) echo "my-class"; ?>" >
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I add everything in page-template.php this is what I get: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_metabox()Still don't understand how to add those values in checkbox or list metabox.

Comment: I agree that it won't work. That's why I call it a fake function. You'll need to use the same function you used to get the array in your original question. I did forget to add the key for the variable, which I added here.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what to add and where. If I add "get_meta_boxes" instead of get_metabox it doesn't work. This is metabox file: https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/demo/demo.php

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for register_meta_boxes(), ...Notice: Undefined index: std ...

Comment: Updated this answer based on [this page of documentation](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/helper-function-to-get-meta-value/)

Comment: OK, this update is better I see that it adds div class="" in page. If I want to define checkbox (and I added "checkbox" as meta key) I don't understand where to add those 2 options for this (actually 1 class I want to add/remove via checkbox)? Should they be added in demo.php ? https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/demo/demo.php

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for reading the documentation.

Comment: I'm reading it all day but it doesn't say anything for someone who is not familiar with php even the code you wrote to me didn't exist in that "documentation", and it should be something basic, thanks anyway.

Comment: ALL TIME there was problem because of password metabox which required password and post/page didn't even updated because of that field. So my advice DON'T FORGET TO REMOVE THIS FROM YOUR METABOX PLUGIN:
    array(
    'name' => __( 'Password', 'rwmb' ),
    'id' => "{$prefix}password",
    'type' => 'password',
    ),

Comment: Now all works fine, 
cpilko thanks again, btw nice avatar image. :)